# why this assembly program is loaded from the address 0B3D:0000?

Tags: assembly, dos

I have seen a assembly program written from a book about assemble:

```
assume cs:code
   code segment 
   dw 0123h,0456h,0789h,0abch,0defh,0fedh,0cbah,0987h
   mov bx,0
   mov ax,0

   mov cx,8
s: add ax,cs:[bx]
   add bx,2
   loop s

   mov ax,4c00h
   int 21h
 code ends
 end
```

This program's function is to add eight numbers. The author compiled this program in the

**DOS** and use the  **DEBUG** to see how this program be loaded.

The author use the **R** command and got that

> DS = 0B2DH ES = 0B2D  SS = 0B3D  CS = 0B3D IP = 0000

And then the author said that this program is loaded from the address **0B3D:0000**.

I'm a confused that why this program is loaded from the address **0B3D:0000**?

Is this because the existence of the **Program Segment Prefix**(PSP)?

If the answer is the existence of the **PSP**, what is in the **PSP**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, for every program DOS creates a so-called `Program Segment Prefix` and when a program starts, the DS and ES segment registers are loaded with the segment address of its PSP.

In the PSP there are a number of things useful to DOS itself and potentially to the application. The most useful one is the program's command line. I've never used any other PSP fields, just the command line.

You can see what's inside the PSP [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Segment_Prefix), [here](https://idlebox.net/2006/helppc21/HelpPC-2.10-HTML/table-Program_Segment_Prefix.html), [here](http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AoA/DOS/ch13/CH13-8.html#HEADING8-103), [here](http://www.sxlist.com/techref/dos/psps.htm) and in many other places.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't describe the question precisely and let you misunderstand my question.Now I revised my question.Thanks for your answer anyway!!!!